# Why do jQuery plugins conflict, and how to avoid them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I often combine multiple jQuery plugins and only to find them not working properly together.

The below example combines 2 effects: thumbnails appear one by one, and disappearing scroll bar.

This one has both jQuery toward the bottom of the html, but only "appear one by one" is working. It somehow disabled the scroll bar function:

http://heidixu.com/creative/test/index2.html

And this one has "appear one by one" jQuery commented out, and display: none; from the css taken out, all a sudden the scroll bar function is working again:

http://heidixu.com/creative/test/index2.html mouse over content area to see scroll bar appear and disappear.

How do I have multiple plugins working together?

Thanks much!

Edit: to make it easier, I thought I attache the code to this.

disappearing scroll bar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                // the element we want to apply the jScrollPane
                var $el                 = $('#jp-container').jScrollPane({
                    verticalGutter  : -16
                }),

                // the extension functions and options  
                    extensionPlugin     = {

                        extPluginOpts   : {
                            // speed for the fadeOut animation
                            mouseLeaveFadeSpeed : 500,
                            // scrollbar fades out after hovertimeout_t milliseconds
                            hovertimeout_t      : 1000,
                            // if set to false, the scrollbar will be shown on mouseenter and hidden on mouseleave
                            // if set to true, the same will happen, but the scrollbar will be also hidden on mouseenter after "hovertimeout_t" ms
                            // also, it will be shown when we start to scroll and hidden when stopping
                            useTimeout          : true,
                            // the extension only applies for devices with width > deviceWidth
                            deviceWidth         : 980
                        },
                        hovertimeout    : null, // timeout to hide the scrollbar
                        isScrollbarHover: false,// true if the mouse is over the scrollbar
                        elementtimeout  : null, // avoids showing the scrollbar when moving from inside the element to outside, passing over the scrollbar
                        isScrolling     : false,// true if scrolling
                        addHoverFunc    : function() {

                            // run only if the window has a width bigger than deviceWidth
                            if( $(window).width() <= this.extPluginOpts.deviceWidth ) return false;

                            var instance        = this;

                            // functions to show / hide the scrollbar
                            $.fn.jspmouseenter  = $.fn.show;
                            $.fn.jspmouseleave  = $.fn.fadeOut;

                            // hide the jScrollPane vertical bar
                            var $vBar           = this.getContentPane().siblings('.jspVerticalBar').hide();

                            /*
                             * mouseenter / mouseleave events on the main element
                             * also scrollstart / scrollstop - @James Padolsey : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/
                             */
                            $el.bind('mouseenter.jsp',function() {

                                // show the scrollbar
                                $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseenter();

                                if( !instance.extPluginOpts.useTimeout ) return false;

                                // hide the scrollbar after hovertimeout_t ms
                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                instance.hovertimeout   = setTimeout(function() {
                                    // if scrolling at the moment don't hide it
                                    if( !instance.isScrolling )
                                        $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                                }, instance.extPluginOpts.hovertimeout_t );


                            }).bind('mouseleave.jsp',function() {

                                // hide the scrollbar
                                if( !instance.extPluginOpts.useTimeout )
                                    $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                                else {
                                clearTimeout( instance.elementtimeout );
                                if( !instance.isScrolling )
                                        $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                                }

                            });

                            if( this.extPluginOpts.useTimeout ) {

                                $el.bind('scrollstart.jsp', function() {

                                    // when scrolling show the scrollbar
                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                instance.isScrolling    = true;
                                $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseenter();

                            }).bind('scrollstop.jsp', function() {

                                    // when stop scrolling hide the scrollbar (if not hovering it at the moment)
                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                instance.isScrolling    = false;
                                instance.hovertimeout   = setTimeout(function() {
                                    if( !instance.isScrollbarHover )
                                            $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                                    }, instance.extPluginOpts.hovertimeout_t );

                            });

                                // wrap the scrollbar
                                // we need this to be able to add the mouseenter / mouseleave events to the scrollbar
                            var $vBarWrapper    = $('<div/>').css({
                                position    : 'absolute',
                                left        : $vBar.css('left'),
                                top         : $vBar.css('top'),
                                right       : $vBar.css('right'),
                                bottom      : $vBar.css('bottom'),
                                width       : $vBar.width(),
                                height      : $vBar.height()
                            }).bind('mouseenter.jsp',function() {

                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                clearTimeout( instance.elementtimeout );

                                instance.isScrollbarHover   = true;

                                    // show the scrollbar after 100 ms.
                                    // avoids showing the scrollbar when moving from inside the element to outside, passing over the scrollbar                              
                                instance.elementtimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                    $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseenter();
                                }, 100 );   

                            }).bind('mouseleave.jsp',function() {

                                    // hide the scrollbar after hovertimeout_t
                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                instance.isScrollbarHover   = false;
                                instance.hovertimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                        // if scrolling at the moment don't hide it
                                    if( !instance.isScrolling )
                                            $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                                    }, instance.extPluginOpts.hovertimeout_t );

                            });

                            $vBar.wrap( $vBarWrapper );

                        }

                        }

                    },

                    // the jScrollPane instance
                    jspapi          = $el.data('jsp');

                // extend the jScollPane by merging 
                $.extend( true, jspapi, extensionPlugin );
                jspapi.addHoverFunc();

            });
        </script>
```

Thumbnails appear one by one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                // Start showing the divs
                showDiv();
            });

            function showDiv() {
                // If there are hidden divs left
                if($('div:hidden').length) {
                    // Fade the first of them in
                    $('div:hidden:first').fadeIn();
                    // And wait one second before fading in the next one
                    setTimeout(showDiv, 500);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, jquery plugins are supposed to work independently.

There are several reasons why they may not, but all are dependent upon flaws with one or both of the plugins themselves.

You will often get jquery plug-ins failing due to conflict of HTML class name, id, etc. For instance, a disappearing scroll-bar is very likely some conflicting CSS that didn't play nicely when used from your tool.

Also common: Some jquery selector within the plug-in overwrites some html writing from another tool.

A work-around - use iframe elements to separate the two pages from each other.

Or look into the plug-ins and see if there is any way to create a prefix to the classnames utilized by the plugin. This may help because it will keep your css class names independent.

Otherwise, just look into the DOM from firebug or another tool. See what CSS styles and HTML elements are involved in the issue to get a hint at something you might do to fix it.